# Invalid time message when creating "Date" object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, date

I have a React Native app, running React Native 0.71.9 and React 18.

I have an API returning data and I parse that data into models (using Mobx). When I try to create a new `Date` object using the format `"mm/dd/yy"` (e.g. 09/03/23) it returns "Invalid time".

This happens usually when running the app in Pacific timezone, when current date is the day before to the date I want to parse.

The purpose is to get the date with midnight time.

```
// Today is 09/02/23, in Pacific timezone
// It's in 09/03/23 in UCT time
const date = new Date("09/03/23") // returns "Invalid time". Instead I'd like to get 09/03/23 00:00:00
```

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: What exactly is the context for this? Your code works perfectly fine in my browser (Firefox) and in Chrome.

Comment: also the relationship between the input date string and the current time/date is completely unimportant; the Date constructor is happy to construct an instance for any date.

Comment: added more context

Comment: Well another thing to note is that while it may work for *me*, I'm in my own locale, and it's possible that your browser in your locale simply does not like that date format. Really there is only one "official" date format for JavaScript, and that is the ISO format ("2023-09-02").

Comment: @pointy—there are [*three*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse) (not counting a numeric time value or millisecond offset from the epoch).

Comment: @RobG well sure that is the case, but even that is complicated by the fact that different environments are willing to parse miscellaneous non-standard ways of writing dates, according to their own rules, and yet at the same time they won't accept just anything even if the string is understandable in some locales. The answer below is illuminating (to me at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Hypothesis on the problem

The JavaScript specification specifies valid string formats accepted by the date constructor. `MM/DD/YY` is not one of them. The relevant parts of the spec have been quoted below, with irrelevant parts being omitted and some sections re-ordered to help make it easier to understand:

> #### [21.4.2 The Date Constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-constructor)
>
> [...]
>
> ##### 21.4.2.1 Date ( *...values* )
>
> This function performs the following steps when called:
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Else if *numberOfArgs* = 1, then
>
>    [...]
>
>    c. Else,
>
>    - i. Let *v* be ? ToPrimitive(*value*).
>    - ii. If *v* is a String, then
>
>      1. Assert: The next step never returns an abrupt completion because *v* is a String.
>      2. Let *tv* be the result of parsing *v* as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the **`parse`** method (21.4.3.2).

> ##### [21.4.3.2 Date.parse ( *string* )](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.parse)
>
> [...] The function first attempts to parse the String according to the format described in Date Time String Format (21.4.1.32), including expanded years. If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats. [...]
>
> If the String conforms to the Date Time String Format, substitute values take the place of absent format elements. When the `MM` or `DD` elements are absent, **"01"** is used. When the `HH`, `mm`, or `ss` elements are absent, **"00"** is used. When the `sss` element is absent, **"000"** is used. When the UTC offset representation is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.
>
> If `x` is any Date whose milliseconds amount is zero within a particular implementation of ECMAScript, then all of the following expressions should produce the same numeric value in that implementation, if all the properties referenced have their initial values:
>
> `x.valueOf()` 
> `Date.parse(x.toString())` 
> `Date.parse(x.toUTCString())` 
> `Date.parse(x.toISOString())`

> ##### [21.4.1.32 Date Time String Format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format)
>
> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format. The format is as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

Even though `MM/DD/YY` is not in the spec, non-standard formats are permitted by the spec to be parsed in a way as determined by the implementers of the JavaScript runtime.

In React Native, there are two possible JavaScript runtimes ([reference](https://reactnative.dev/docs/javascript-environment)):

- [Hermes](https://hermesengine.dev/)
- [JavaScriptCore](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/tree/main/Source/JavaScriptCore)

Hermes only supports formats defined in the spec ([reference](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/136#issuecomment-543382503)). I also tested by evaluating `new Date("09/03/23")` in the Hermes REPL and it returned `[Date Invalid]`.

JavaScriptCore seems to support `MM/DD/YY`. WebKit browsers use JavaScriptCore so I tested by evaluating `new Date("09/03/23")` in the console in Safari (a WebKit browser). It returned `Sun Sep 03 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`.

As a result, I hypothesise different versions of your app may be running different JavaScript runtimes. The version running Hermes will error while the version running JavaScriptCore won't.

## Testing the hypothesis

Some initial questions that might validate the hypothesis without too much effort:

- **Did you recently [enable Hermes](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#enabling-hermes-on-older-versions-of-react-native) in your app?**
- **Did you recently upgrade React Native?** Hermes was available in 0.64 and enabled by default in 0.70 ([reference](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#enabling-hermes-on-older-versions-of-react-native)).
- **Does the problem only affect a certain version range of your app?**

If the answers to the above questions aren't helpful in validating the hypothesis then you will probably need to check if Hermes is enabled now and wasn't before. Check the [configuration for enabling Hermes](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#enabling-hermes-on-older-versions-of-react-native) and step through your codebase history to verify if Hermes was disabled/enabled and when.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed answer.

Yes, this new version has Hermes enabled and went from RN 0.69 to 0.71.9. I will try disabling hermes and check its behavior.

Comment: @FelipePeña: great, sounds like there's a path to follow. If you have control of the API, I'd recommend changing the format of the date it returns to a standard format. If you don't, I wouldn't recommend disabling Hermes just to fix this (it's comparable to using a sledgehammer on a drawing pin). I'd write a function to parse the non-standard format into a standard format.

Answer (score -1):

Consider appending the desired timezone:

```
const date = new Date("09/03/23 00:00:00 GMT-0700");  // For Pacific Daylight Time
```

Comment: I added more context. If I get "09/03/23", regardless of the loca device timezone, I'd like to get in return "09/03/23 00:00:00"

Comment: @FelipePeña well you're talking about two separate phases with different problems. First, there's getting the runtime to *parse* your input date string. Once you get that to work, your next problem is how to format the output when converting your Date instance to a string.

Comment: Yes, thank you @FelipePeña, I wrote a function for this.


```function formatDate(input) {
    const [month, day, year] = input.split("/");
    const date = new Date(Date.UTC(Number("20" + year), Number(month) - 1, Number(day)));
    
    const formatted = month.padStart(2, '0') + "/" + day.padStart(2, '0') + "/" + year.slice(-2) + " 00:00:00";
    
    return formatted;
}

const result = formatDate("09/03/23");
console.log(result);  // Outputs "09/03/23 00:00:00"```

Comment: Replacing one unsupported format with another is not a good idea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).